# regression model for zero-inflated pseudo-continuous outcomes with negative values and practical solution in R?

Tags: regression, distributions, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, zero-inflation

I am looking high and low for how to model data where the outcome is pseudo-continuous (change in questionnaire scores) that can be negative and has a lot of "true" zeroes. I see talk about models for zero-inflated count data, i.e. positive integer outcomes like zero-inflated poisson/ZIP, zero-inflated negative binomial/ZINB, and hurdle models, but nothing for non-count outcomes with negative values. I would also be interested in practical solutions for frequentist and Bayesian modeling in R. Documentation for the R [GAMLSS package](https://www.gamlss.com/) for additive models refers to continuous distributions, but the link to the documentation on that is dead.

Thanks in advance for any pointers,
gj

Comment: Would a `{glmmTMB}` (in R) zero-inflated Gaussian work?

Comment: Would modelling the second score using the first score in addition to your covariates be an option? At least you would only have to deal with the positive scores for which there would be a number of distributions?

Comment: Thank you, @AlexJ and @GavinSimpson, for your responses. I was looking exactly for a zero-inflated Gaussian but couldn't find it (didn't see it in `glmmTMB`) -- where and what is it? I tried `metagenomeSeq::zigControl()` (but couldn't get that to work) and `EnvStats::ezmnorm`, which I'm trying to figure out now, I've gone through the packages listed on the [CRAN-R page on distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) and haven't found anything else...

I am actually also modeling the baseline/first score -- but it's not exactly the same score/questionnaire....

Comment: @gj. see the examples for `glmmTMB`, e.g. for `m1 <- ....`. You specify the family as `gaussian`, and `ziformula = ~ 1` (or other terms if you want a more complex zero-inflated model).